# How to deal with multiple services inside a docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have been using a Microservices architecture for develop my software, and I have running my services using Docker Compose, but my problem is when the new services were created I have to add them into the docker-compose.yml, and then I got about 200+ hundred lines of code inside the docker-compose.yml, and I have around 17 services for now which the services have related each other.

Then my question is "How to manage the docker-compose.yml to be easy to maintain and clean?"

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
   mongo:
     container_name: mongodb
     image: mongo:3.4.7
     volumes:
       - ./mongo/data:/data/db
     ports:
       - 54321:27017
     networks:
       - zensorium_backend
     restart: always
     command: mongod --smallfiles

   golang_oauth:
     container_name: golang_oauth
     build: .
     volumes:
        - ./oauth:/go/src/oauth
     working_dir: /go/src/oauth
     ports:
        - 8080:8082
     depends_on:
        - mongo
     env_file:
       - ./.api.env
     networks:
       - zensorium_backend
     command: realize start --run
     restart: always

   golang_account:
     container_name: golang_account
     build: .
     volumes:
        - ./account:/go/src/account
     working_dir: /go/src/account
     ports:
        - 8081:8082
     depends_on:
        - mongo
     env_file:
       - ./.api.env
     networks:
       - zensorium_backend
     command: realize start --run
     restart: always

   golang_client:
     container_name: golang_client
     build: .
     volumes:
        - ./client:/go/src/client
     working_dir: /go/src/client
     ports:
        - 8082:8082
     depends_on:
        - mongo
     env_file:
       - ./.api.env
     networks:
       - zensorium_backend
     command: realize start --run
     restart: always

   golang_mail:
     container_name: golang_mail
     build: .
     volumes:
        - ./mail:/go/src/mail
     working_dir: /go/src/mail
     expose:
        - 8082
     depends_on:
        - mongo
     env_file:
        - ./.api.env
     networks:
        - zensorium_backend
     command: realize start --run
     restart: always

   golang_user:
     container_name: golang_user
     build: .
     volumes:
        - ./user:/go/src/user
     working_dir: /go/src/user
     ports:
        - 8083:8082
     depends_on:
        - mongo
     env_file:
        - ./.api.env
     networks:
        - zensorium_backend
     command: realize start --run
     restart: always

   golang_gateway2:
     container_name: golang_gateway2
     build: .
     volumes:
        - ./gateway2:/go/src/gateway
     working_dir: /go/src/gateway
     ports:
        - 8084:8082
     depends_on:
        - mongo
     env_file:
       - ./.api.env
     networks:
        - zensorium_backend
     command: realize start --run
     restart: always

   golang_measurement:
     container_name: golang_measurement
     build: .
     volumes:
        - ./measurement:/go/src/measurement
     working_dir: /go/src/measurement
     ports:
        - 8085:8082
     depends_on:
        - mongo
     env_file:
        - ./.api.env
     networks:
        - zensorium_backend
     command: realize start --run
     restart: always

   golang_app:
     container_name: golang_app
     build: .
     volumes:
        - ./app:/go/src/app
     working_dir: /go/src/app
     ports:
        - 8086:8082
     depends_on:
        - mongo
     env_file:
        - ./.api.env
     networks:
        - zensorium_backend
     command: realize start --run
     restart: always

   golang_logging:
     container_name: golang_logging
     build: .
     volumes:
        - ./logging:/go/src/logging
     working_dir: /go/src/logging
     ports:
        - 8087:8082

     networks:
        - zensorium_backend
     command: realize start --run
     restart: always

   golang_notify:
     container_name: golang_notify
     build: .
     volumes:
        - ./notify:/go/src/notify
     working_dir: /go/src/notify
     ports:
        - 8088:8082
     env_file:
        - ./.api.env
     networks:
        - zensorium_backend
     command: realize start --run
     restart: always

   golang_routine:
     container_name: golang_routine
     build: .
     volumes:
       - ./routine:/go/src/routine
     working_dir: /go/src/routine
     ports:
       - 8089:8082
     env_file:
       - ./.api.env
     networks:
       - zensorium_backend
     command: realize start --run
     restart: always

   angular_cli:
     container_name: angular_cli
     build: ./angular-cli
     ports:
       - "4200:4200"
     networks:
       - zensorium_frontend
     working_dir: /home/node/webPortal
     volumes:
       - ./angular-cli/webPortal:/home/node/webPortal
       - /home/node/webPortal/node_modules
     restart: always
     command: npm start

   golang_dev:
       container_name: golang_dev
       build: .
       volumes:
          - ./dev:/go/src/dev
       working_dir: /go/src/dev
       ports:
         - 8090:8082
       env_file:
         - ./.api.env
       networks:
         - zensorium_backend
       command: realize start --run
       restart: always

networks:
  zensorium_backend:
    driver: bridge
  zensorium_frontend:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 3):

my recommendation is to keep the `docker-compose.yml` as little as possible if you have a lot of services defined. For example you could write the definition inline, use `.env` file so you dont always have to specify it, remove the `container_name`. Moving `working_dir` to Dockerfile. If you are using version 2, you can use the [inheritance of service](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services) but this feature is not supported in docker-compose 3 and newer... You should also use named volumes.

example of inline `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.4.7
    command: mongod --smallfiles
    restart: always
    ports: ["54321:27017"]
    networks: [zensorium_backend]
    volumes: ["my_mongo_data:/data/db"]


  golang_oauth:
    build: .
    command: realize start --run
    restart: always
    working_dir: /go/src/oauth # could be moved do Dockerfile
    ports: ["8080:8082"]
    depends_on: [mongo]
    environment: ["VAR_1=${VAR_1}","VAR2=${VAR2}"] # using .env file
    networks: [zensorium_backend]
    volumes: ["my_oauth_data:/go/src/oauth"]

volumes:
  my_mongo_data:
  my_oauth_data:

networks:
  zensorium_backend:
    driver: bridge
  zensorium_frontend:
    driver: bridge
```

and .env file in same folder as the .yml

```
VAR_1=mazel
VAR2=tov
```

Comment: Thanks! @Mazel Tov, Can I ask you one more question?

You've said that "keep the docker-compose.yml as little as possible", so that's mean I should separate the services as one service one docker-compose file and then if I separated it, I will get many docker-compose files right?

Then how do I run the docker-compose files at once?

Thanks again.

Comment: You can load more files with -f option, but what i meant is to stick with one file and write definitions in-line to have more overview. This is ok for me and doesnt have to suit others though

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the possibilities of yaml to write repeated strings in shorter way. For example :

```
---
version: '3.4'
x-command: &command bash -c "ls &&  sleep infinity"

services:

  service1:
    command: *command

  service2:
    command: *command
```

And man can use templates:
https://matthiasnoback.nl/2018/03/defining-multiple-similar-services-with-docker-compose/